# GridFS does not play well with AfNetworking or remote downloading of images

Tags: ios, mongodb, afnetworking, gridfs

I have an app that used GridFS to store the images of a document (references). I am trying to use AfNetworking to download the images when a UITableViewCell is shown. However AFNetworking does not have a method that deals with image data that is stored in binary form i.e. it asks for a physical URL on the server. Please see (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) under image downloads. I trealy need to use AFNetworking methods for caching etc.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridFS is a filesystem. If you want to serve images over HTTP, which is something AFNetworking can handle, you'll need to set that up to a web server.

Apache and Nginx appear to both have modules to server GridFS, so that'd be a good place to start.